# Android Studio. Emulator works. App does not run

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm using Androiod Studio 2.1.3. I've made an app. No errors, the Emulator comes up, it works, acts like a phone. Problem is that the app does not run. I cleared all the errors except I saw one:

> Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD
>   Nexus_5_API_23

Also, I tried rebuilding the app and got the Following :

> Exception in thread "png-cruncher_62" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt
>   execute at
>   C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.2\aapt.exe
>   can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting
>   environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5
>   seconds
>       at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
>       at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
>       at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

And that's repeated several times with a different number on the png-cruncher. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I saw png-cruncher_62 on your log, make sure to never use - in image name (you can use only _ like png_cruncher_62 will work), android will not take it. If it's still not working, try to create a new emulator and make sure its updated in SDK Manager :)